# с++ объявление глобального обекта класса

Tags: классы, c++-cli

//перехожу с билдера на визуалку поэтому туплю везде))
суть проблемы такая есть "пустой класс" сRandom

```
//cRandon.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;

ref class Ran {
public:
    ~Ran();
    Ran();
    };

//cRandom.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cRandom.h"

Ran ::Ran(){};
Ran ::~Ran(){};
```

Нужно создать глобальный объект этого класса

```
using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    Ran ^e=gcnew Ran();//пишет ошибку если тоже прописать в "батон" то ОК
        Ran e1;//OK
        int a//OK
```

то что пишет компилятор

```
error C3145: e: глобальная или статическая переменная не может быть управляемого типа "Ran ^"
```

может не объявлять глобальную или статичную переменную или элемент собственного типа,который относится к объекту в куче сборщика мусора

подскажите как правильно создавть ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЕ обекты в динамической обл памяти

зарание спасибо всем

Comment: Какбы приследую такую цель
мне надо создать допустим по клику мышки на форме, обект который будет глабальным для приложения и размещаться в динамической области памяти.

Comment: Это не совсем C++

Answer (score 1):

Пиши `Ran^ e=nullptr`, а выделяй через gcnew отдельно в функции main или ещё где-нибудь.

А зачем тебе `C++\CLI`? Лучше пиши на обычном C++ или на C#. `C++\CLI` слишком громоздкий и годится только для связки неуправляемого кода с управляемым.

*Добавлено:*

Хотя нет. Там даже ссылку глобальную объявить нельзя. Вариант выше не сработает. Есть другой вариант: создай класс, хранящий нужные тебе ссылки. Создай его экземпляр в глобальной области видимости, если можно:

```
struct Global
{
    Ran^ e;
};

Global global;

int main()
{
    global.e=gcnew Ran;
    ...
}
```

Если компилятора и это не устроит, то в глобальной области видимости объяви указатель на объект этого класса, а объект создай в функции main:

```
struct Global
{
    Ran^ e;
};

Global* global;

int main()
{
    global=new Global;
    global->e=gcnew Ran;
    ...
}
```

Comment: В чем посоветуете писать десктоп преложения под windows на с++? 
(Qt не предлогать) 
Buider //не катируется у роботадателя и всяких гуру
MFC //как я понял тот еще бред

Comment: Зачем именно C++? Чем C# не подходит? Он для оконных приложений лучше всего. Там тот же Windows Forms, но язык не загромождён кучей способов сделать одно и то же. Там есть только часть, ответственная за управляемый код. Код на C# выглядит даже более похожим на C++, чем этот C++\CLI.

>Qt не предлогать

Почему? Хоть я сам не пробовал, но все почему-то нахваливают.

>MFC //как я понял тот еще бред

Да, MFC это жуть. Зачем-то обработку событий сделали через макросы. Кстати, я пишу свой набор классов на C++, используя чистый Windows API. Там всё удобнее и лучше. Только функциональности пока мало.

Comment: По Qt есть книги на русском.

Comment: Если ты понял C++\CLI, то легко сможешь изучить C#. Там всё очень похоже: синтаксис стандартного C++, а возможности те, которые добавлены в C++\CLI.

 Не понял твоё предложение без знаков препинания. Ты писал, что только по Qt нет книг на русском? Или C# с Java тоже? По C# книг на русском полно.

Comment: про Qt что нет норм книг имел ввиду.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Попробуй. Если сработает, не забудь принять ответ и поставить плюсик.

 Правка: а, у тебя ещё нет привилегии голосовать.

Comment: искал ответ на свой вопрос наткнулся на эту инфу не совсем то но может кому поможет http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/by40z94e.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Подсказка по созданию глобального объекта класса:

В `.h` класса записываем: `extern MyClass ObjectOfMyClass;` (конструктор без параметров)

В `.cpp` класса записываем: `MyClass ObjectOfMyClass(parameters);` (конструктор с параметрами)

Если создал только `.h`, то записываем в него сразу: `MyClass ObjectOfMyClass(parameters);` (конструктор с параметрами)

Пользуемся классом и методами во всех остальных файлах!